# no network devices available: Xubuntu 18.04 on Lenovo Ideapad Flex 14 IML

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, lenovo, iwlwifi

I just installed Xubuntu 18.04 over the Windows 10 that came with this Lenovo Ideapad Flex 14 IML. It was painful enough figuring out how to get it to boot from a USB stick, and getting Ubuntu to see the machine's hard drive. But once I was running from the Live USB stick, everything worked fine, including wireless networking. So I thought I was on my way to victory.

Once the installation was complete and I rebooted, no wireless. The networking thingy on the upper right panel says "no network devices available." The option "enable wireless" is not displayed.

I can't understand why wireless networking would work when test-driving the live usb, but fail when booting from the new installation on the hard drive. I tried re-installing, making sure I turned on the checkbox that asks if you want to use proprietary 3rd party drivers -- assuming that's the correct choice. (I don't think it's relevant but I also chose, at install time, the option to encrypt the installation and use LVM.)

I tried looking at the "connection information" for the wireless connection when it was working off the live usb. It said it was using the `iwlwifi` driver. Booting off the disk, I tried examining "Additional drivers" through the GUI, and what it displays is not illuminating. It says the device "Intel Corporation: Unknown" is "not working." The three radio buttons that follow are labeled: "Using iwlwifi driver backport in DKMS format...";  "Continue using a manually installed driver"; "Do not use this device." The third is checked and the first is disabled. I tried checking the second, "Continue using a manually installed driver" but got nowhere. The "Revert" and "Apply Changes" buttons at the bottom remain disabled.

The output from `iwconfig`:  `no wireless extensions`.

Not really knowing what I'm doing, I tried removing and reloading the `iwlwifi` module from the kernel usng `modprobe`. That seemed to work without incident but had no effect on this problem.

Should I try re-installing *without* turning on "use 3rd party proprietary..." (whatever the wording is)? I wouldn't expect that to work.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Boot from your USB, install and run the `wireless-info` script { https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info ). Move the `wireless-info` script to your other system, and run it there. Compare outputs.

Comment: YAY! I am deeply indebted to @waltinator for that suggestion. Why? Because the first noteworthy difference between the outputs of `wireless-info` when running from the USB versus the hard drive was *the kernel version.* Now I understand at least the proximate cause of my misery. The USB runs kernel version Linux 5.3.0-28; the installer installs the newer Linux 5.3.0-42, and GRUB boots from that by default. But that more recent kernel version, whatever its virtues relative to its predecessor, for whatever reasons, evidently does not play well with this wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm indebted to @waltinator for this solution, but I guess it's up to me to post an answer so here goes.

I don't know the ultimate cause but whatever the reason, wireless networking will not work on a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 14 IML (there are likey be others as well) while running Linux kernel version 5.3.0-42. The solution that is working fine for me is simple: *don't boot from that kernel. Stick with the 5.3.0-28 kernel you get when you burn the bootable USB stick*.

This in turn requires you to edit GRUB (or else intervene manually every time you boot, obviously not a good strategy) and there is more than one way to configure GRUB to accomplish this. I took the simplest way out I could find: first, add these lines to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

and run `sudo update-grub` when you're done.

Then reboot, using the GRUB boot menu item "Advanced options" to select the 5.3.0-28 kernel. (If the boot menu is bypassed, you might have to hold down the Shift key -- or is it Escape? not able to double-check that right now -- during the boot process to make it display.)

I hope this saves someone a few hours of anguish.